# Synchronization with nested class but with a global variable? (JAVA)

Tags: java, synchronization, nested, nested-class, locks

I am trying to figure what would be the best way to fix this broken concurrency issue with this kind of code. I have tried adding a lock around "index++" but is there a better way of achieving concurrency?

```
    public class MainClass {
        public static short index = 0;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            MainClass testConc = new MainClass();
            Thread thr1 = new Thread(testConc.new MyRunnable());
            thr1.start();
            Thread thr2 = new Thread(testConc.new MyRunnable());
            thr2.start();
        }    

        class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
            private static final Object lock = new Object();
            public void run() { 
                while (index < 99) {
                    System.out.println(index);
                    synchronized(lock) {
                        index++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How is the concurrency "broken"? What do you expect as output and what are you getting?

Comment: @jas it is a static field so it is a shared lock

Comment: @jas, the lock object is `static` which means that it's shared between all instances.

Comment: @MickMnemonic I tried to run it. It sometimes finishes with the output like "97, 98, 5" etc.

Comment: @TomášZíma could that be because it is printing outside the lock?

Comment: Are you sure your code compiles? I'm getting an error from the `lock` instance variable: "static fields can only be declared in static or top level types", which is why the `static` modifier cannot be used there.

Comment: @thestranger yeah, exactly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have the lock at the same level (`MainClass`) as the data it is used for protecting. Class variable `index` should actually have `private` scope, because synchronization only happens in-class.

Also, as pointed out by Tomáš in the comment, the variable should be marked as `volatile`, which guarantees that any changes to the its value are visible to all threads (since Java 5). This removes the need to synchronize read access to `index`. So the corrected code looks something like:

```
public class MainClass {
  private static volatile short index = 0;
  private static final Object lock = new Object();
  ...
```

If you want the program to output the indices from `0` to `98` in order and only once per index value, you need to modify the `run()` method into this:

```
public void run() {
    while (index < 99) {
        synchronized (lock) {                    
            // double-check for threads that made it here
            // before #index got incremented to 99 by the thread that
            // made the final increment
            if (index < 99) {
                System.out.println(index);
                index++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that a [double-check](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) for `index < 99` is required because `index` may have been changed by an another thread after the value was evaluated in the `while` condition. You'll see this if you increase the number of threads that are spawned by `MainClass` using the old version of `run()`.

Comment: Class variable `index` should be also declared `volatile` to let JVM know its value could be manipulated by different threads.

Comment: @TomášZíma But can a short be declared `volatile`?

Comment: @thestranger Yes, it can.

Comment: Thanks @TomášZíma, I edited the post regarding the usage of `volatile`.

Answer (score 0):

AtomicInteger would be better than locking around index++
It is designed especially for that use case.

Also by locking you are not achieving concurrency but thread safety/atomicity (if implemented properly).

By the way, I don't see the 'broken concurrency issue' in your code.

Comment: I cant change index from short to anything else. So keeping that in mind, would there be other solutions. And the broken concurrency is if i didn't have ' synchronized(lock) '. Would it work if i made the ' run() ' synchronized?

Comment: not it would not work with synchronized run(). It would 'synchronized' run() independently on each thread, so there will be no synchronization at all. In terms of performance using ReentrantLock is better than synchronized(obj). I am sure you can 'change' index to something else as you are already messing up wiht it with your threads, do consider it (you can write getter that provide the value as short)